# Inequality that came up on the power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone explain the inequality - from chapter 3 on power series Visual Complex Functions - An Introduction with Phase Portraits - Elias Wegert - Birkhauser press.
My first confusion is in(3.45) the second equation: the first n terms vanish at $z=z_0.$ So when the index starts at k=n, the k=1,2,..,n-1 have vanishes and the first $a_{n,n} $ coefficient. In that case why not start the sum one further along?

Please explain the inequalities on page 94 in the last part of the proof of Theorem 3.2.11. Particularly, how or why the k change to n. Is for $\delta^k$ I think because the largest power it takes in the sum is when k=n. But that's not the case when dividing by a power of $r^k$

[image]
[image]
[image]

$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\left| {{b_n}} \right|} \sum\limits_{}^{} {\left| {{a_{nk}}} \right|} {\left| {z - {z_0}} \right|^k} \le \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{d}{{{r^n}}}} \sum\limits_{k = n}^M {\frac{{{c^n}}}{{{r^k}}}{\delta ^k}}  \le \frac{{dr}}{{r - \delta }}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} {\left( {\frac{{c\delta }}{{{r^2}}}} \right)} ^n}\\
 \le \frac{{dr}}{{r - \delta }}\frac{{{r^2}}}{{{r^2} - c\delta }}.$$

Where $\delta $ is chosen so small that $\delta  \lt \min (r,{r^2}/c)$ 
 $M,N \in \mathbb{N} $ 
 $\left| {{a_{nk}}} \right| \leqslant {c^n}{r^{ - k}} 
\left| {{b_n}} \right| \leqslant d{r^{ - n}} $
I clearly need $$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{d}{r^n}  = \frac{dr}{r-\delta}$$
So 
$$\frac{dr}{r-\delta}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d}{r^n}=\frac{d}{1-\frac{\delta}{r}}$$
and $\frac{\delta}r\lt 1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\delta < \frac{r^2}{c} \Rightarrow \frac{c\delta}{r^2} < 1 \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^N\Big(\frac{c\delta}{r^2}\Big)^n < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{c\delta}{r^2}\Big)^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{c\delta}{r^2}} = \frac{r^2}{r^2-c\delta}$$

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, that is a good answer but I have just realized that I don't properly understand where the d r divided by r minus delta comes from can you add as a supplemental to the question? I combined the r-to-the-n with the r-to-the-k=n.

Comment: You should apply the same trick with the sum of the infinite geometric progression for the inner sum.

Comment: I have edited the original. I have shown that the inequalities come from a proof.I thought I understood then looked back and realized I didn't.